Intuition for Symmetry while calculating Mean of Hypergeometric Distribution
I'm studying discrete probability, and one of the example problems in my text is:
Let $X \sim \ Hypergeometric(b, r, k)$.
Determine $E(X)$.
Definition of Hypergeometric Distribution: The random experiment behind the hypergeometric distribution involves a bag that contains $b$ blue marbles and $r$ red marbles. $k$ marbles, $k < b + r$, are chosen at random (without replacement). $X$ represents the number of blue marbles in the sample.
The book splits $X$ into $k$ indicator variables $X_1$ through $X_k$ where $X_i$ is 1 if the $i^{th}$ chosen marble is blue, and 0 if otherwise. Then, by linearity of expectation, we can write $E(X) = \sum_{i=1}^{k}E(X_i)$. The book then says that $E(X_i) = \frac{b}{b+r}$ by symmetry. This is the part I don't get.
I don't see the symmetry here: the probability that the second marble is blue depends on whether the first chosen marble is blue or not. Now, I agree that the math works out:
$P($second chosen marble is blue$)$ = $P($second marble is blue given first is red$)\times{P(}$first marble is red$)$+$P($second marble is blue given first is blue$)\times{P(}$first marble is blue$) = \frac{b}{b+r}$
But I don't intuitively understand this.

Imagine that all the $N\; (=b+r)$ marbles are sequentially numbered $1\;thru\; N$. Now all sequences of numbers are equally likely, so the probability that a paticular numbered ball is at position i is $\frac{1}{b+r}$, and so P(it is a blue ball) $=\frac{b}{b+r}$
Or think of it this way. A blue marble (or a marble of any color, for that matter) has no preference for position, so it is equally likely to be at any position, so the probability of it being at position i is the same as its being at the first postion  =$\frac{b}{b+r}$

Thank you! This makes sense. I don't know what it is about this problem, but it is literally the same as the following problem:
You choose any 3 numbers without replacement from the set of integers from 1 to 6. What is the probability that the second number you sample is even?
